# I want to compare values from one array with values of another array

Tags: php, arrays, compare

after the search, The script riches the folder and read each individual file
and if it found h1 it will put each word of it in the array `$h1words`
the problem is, i want to compare the two arrays `$words` and `$h1words`
and if there is one similar character, then it will show the h1

```
if (isset($_GET["sub"]) && $_GET["sub"]=="Search"){

    // Open a known directory, and proceed to read its contents
    $dir="c1/cat1/";
    $words=explode(" ",$_GET["search"]);
    if (is_dir($dir)) {
        if ($dh = opendir($dir)) {
            while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {
                if ($file=="" or $file=="." or $file==".." or $file=="index.php" or $file=="index.html") {
                    continue;
                }

                $filet=$dir.$file;
                if (is_readable($filet)){
                    $filee=fopen($filet,"r");
                    while(!feof($filee)){
                        $str=strip_tags(fgets($filee),"<h1>");
                        $findme="<h1>";
                        $pos = strpos($str, $findme);
                        if ($pos!==false){
                            $h1words=explode(" ",$str);
                        }else{}

                    }
            echo "<br /><hr /><br />";
            fclose($filee);
                }

            }
            closedir($dh);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use the following technique, use a for loop and iterate over the 1st array you take the first index and compeare that one against all of the elements in the 2nd array, you do the following until you run out of elements on the 1st array.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through the first array and compare each value to each value of the second array:

```
$i = 0
foreach($words as $array1){
  foreach($h1words as $array2){
    if($array1 === $array2){
      //equal
    }else{
      //not equal
    }
  }
  $i++
}
```

This will loop through each value in `$words` and compare it to each value in `$h1words`.

Answer (score 0):

now It worked with preg_match(), thnx for your help

```
foreach($words as $wd){
    foreach($h1words as $wh){
    $findd=$wd;
    $text=$wh;
    if (preg_match("/".$findd."/i",$text)){
        echo $str;

    }else{continue;}
```